# Compare two items based on their names

Tags: string, compare, e-commerce, bots

I'm programming a bot in Java with HtmlUnit that gets data (name and price) from two different e-commerce sites, A and B.

Once I have gathered all items in a csv file (name ; price) i try to compare them **to know which items are the same**.

Rarely the name of an A item is equals to name of a B item, but often they have some similarities such as model name or brand name.

Someone have an idea or knows a mechanism to compare this items and know if they are the same item?

Edit:

At least there are 82,000 itemA and 2000 itemB, and I need a injective function that assigns it.

itemA is composed of: brand name and model name. (Structure -> Good).

itemB is composed of: Descriptive text with the brand name and model name inside, without any structure.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `String equals() Method`. This method compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object. Below is an example of working code:

```
  String Str1 = new String("This is really not immutable!!");
  String Str2 = Str1;
  String Str3 = new String("This is really not immutable!!");
  boolean retVal;

  retVal = Str1.equals( Str2 );
  System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );

  retVal = Str1.equals( Str3 );
  System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );
```

This method returns true if the String are equal; false otherwise.

Comment: Rarely ItemA.name.equals( ItemB.name ), but they have common regions (like model number or brand name).
I split item B in words and used .equals() function to compare every word with A.modelName, but it fail in many cases.

Comment: @ismael-gandarillas Could you post your code, this will provide me with better idea of your problem, leading to better solution.